# How can I apply list of replacement rules properly to a data after importing the data?

Tags: import, replacement, list-manipulation

I have a list of data in which each element has its name as follows:

```
Inputparameters3 = \!\(\*
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{"\"\<ME4\>\"", "->", "401"}], 
RowBox[{"\"\<MtE4\>\"", "->", "344"}]},
{
RowBox[{"\"\<ME4\>\"", "->", "274"}], 
RowBox[{"\"\<MtE4\>\"", "->", "369"}]},
{
RowBox[{"\"\<ME4\>\"", "->", "314"}], 
RowBox[{"\"\<MtE4\>\"", "->", "268"}]}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{
       "Columns" -> {{Center}}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, 
        "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[0.7]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}, "RowsIndexed" -> {}}], "", ")"}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
MatrixForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\)
```

[image]

I exported the data by a format of data and imported it by a format of table as follows:

[image]

After importing the data, it does not work when I use a replacement rule to call a parameter from the data as follows:

[image]

It looks like the problem which I can not call the parameters arises from the commas in the attached image file, but I am not sure how to solve this problem. Would you anyone hint at this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You constructed a visual form that gets interpreted as the following,  and that is what will be stored:

```
{{"ME4" -> 401, "MtE4" -> 344}, {"ME4" -> 274, "MtE4" -> 369}, {"ME4" -> 314, "MtE4" -> 268}}
```

Assume now that the above is stored in `Inputparameters3`. If you want to store the definition of `Inputparameters3`for later use, `DumpSave` makes it easy. It stores all the definitions necessary to reconstruct a symbol. E.g.

```
Inputparameters3 = {{"ME4" -> 401, "MtE4" -> 344}, {"ME4" -> 274, "MtE4" -> 369}, {"ME4" -> 314, "MtE4" -> 268}};
DumpSave["d:/tmp/test.dat", Inputparameters3];
```

We may now remove `Inputparameters3` or start a new session:

```
Delete[Inputparameters3]
Inputparameters3

(* Inputparameters3 *)
```

, but as soon as way call `Get`(or `<<` for short):

```
Get["d:/tmp/test.dat"]
Inputparameters3

(* {{"ME4" -> 401, "MtE4" -> 344}, {"ME4" -> 274, 
  "MtE4" -> 369}, {"ME4" -> 314, "MtE4" -> 268}} *)
```

`Inputparameters3` is fully reconstructed.